# Linq left join with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table of Vehicles and I need to do a left join on VehicleAttribute.

```
var vehicle = (from v in context.Vehicles
                               //join vehicleAttributes
                               join va in context.VehicleAttributes on v.VehicleId equals va.VehicleId into vAttributes
                               from vehicleAttributes in vAttributes.DefaultIfEmpty()

                               where v.VehicleId == vehicleId
                               select new { v, vehicleAttributes });
```

so far so good. VehicleAttribute has also a column AttributeId. And I only need to join those VehicleAttributes when it's in this List:

```
List<Guid> allowedAttributes = (from ua in context.UserAttributes
                                                    where ua.UserId == UserSession.CurrentUser.UserId
                                                    select ua.AttributeId).ToList();
```

How would I do that? I think a subquery might be the right approach but I'm struggling..

Thanks for all answers.

EDIT: A different approach to explain my problem:
I have these two queries

```
SELECT Vehicle.VehicleId,VehicleAttribute.AttributeId
FROM Vehicle
LEFT JOIN VehicleAttribute
ON Vehicle.VehicleId = VehicleAttribute.VehicleId

SELECT UserAttribute.AttributeId
FROM UserAttribute
WHERE UserAttribute.UserId = '4D0F8AD2-7A4D-4E29-A6D3-E5FCD6075388'
```

and want to combine them so I only get the attribute id's which are in the second query. 
A where clause doesn't work because I still want the vehicleId even if there are no attributeIds

Comment: You rather should use navigation properties with EF than explicit joins. I assume you have your mappings set right, since they're not shown here...

Comment: Your first code snippet isn't complete, there are undefined identifiers. Can you post the entire query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you defined `allowedAttributes` you can change

```
vAttributes.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

of your first query to:

```
vAttributes
    .Where(va => allowedAttributes.Contains(va.AttributeId))
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is your scenario. You could try to Left join with a subquery:

```
//define the query that returns allowed VehicleAttributes
allowedAttributesQuery =from ua in context.UserAttributes
                          where ua.UserId == UserSession.CurrentUser.UserId
                          select ua.VehicleAttribute;  //I suppose that VehicleAttribute navigation property exists in the UserAttribute 

//query that joins Vehicles with the allowedAttributes subquery
var vehicle = (from v in context.Vehicles
                           join va in allowedAttributesQuery on v.VehicleId equals va.VehicleId into vAttributes
                           from vehicleAttributes in vAttributes.DefaultIfEmpty()

                           where v.VehicleId == vehicleId
                           select new { v, vehicleAttributes });
```